# How to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have two simple java codes.The first one defines constant power as power = a.pow(b);

```
import java.math.BigInteger;    
public class FermatOne    
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {    
         BigInteger a = new BigInteger ("2");    
         BigInteger k = new BigInteger ("15");    
         BigInteger c = new BigInteger ("1");    
         int b = 332192810;    
         BigInteger n = new BigInteger ("2");    
         BigInteger power;    
         power = a.pow(b);    
         BigInteger exponent;    
         exponent = k.multiply(power);    
         BigInteger mod;    
         mod = exponent.add(c);    
         BigInteger result = n.modPow(exponent,mod);    
         System.out.println("Result is  ==> " + result);    
     }    
}
```

The second one defines constant power as power = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(b)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;    
public class FermatOne    
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {    

         BigInteger k = new BigInteger ("15");    
         BigInteger c = new BigInteger ("1");    
         int b = 332192810;    
         BigInteger n = new BigInteger ("2");    
         BigInteger power;    
         power = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(b);    
         BigInteger exponent;    
         exponent = k.multiply(power);    
         BigInteger mod;    
         mod = exponent.add(c);    
         BigInteger result = n.modPow(exponent,mod);    
         System.out.println("Result is  ==> " + result);    
     }    
}
```

Setting the memory flag -Xmx1024m in the command line the first code works fine , but for the second code I am getting error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError :Java heap space

My question : What should I change in the second code to avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ?

Comment: You are trying to get the result of `2^332192810`? Sorry for disappointing you, but your computer can't handle that kind of computation.

Comment: But that's what the first code does and the poster is saying it works.

Comment: Do you really want to shift left by 332192810 bits?

Comment: @Max,But first code works fine...

Comment: @Max I think he still should not get OOM, as the `a^b mod m` code doesn't actually require computation of the whole `a^b`, and thus, in better implementation memory consumpltion must not be that high.

Comment: @Max: That's only the exponent for `n`. He's actually calculating `2 ^ (15 * 2 ^ 332192809)` !!! ;-)

Comment: @pedja I do not know how and why it works, but I am 105% sure it can't calculate that. Also, I can ensure you that computers won't be able to calculate that in nearest decade for sure.

Comment: @LukasEder But well, he's getting OOM on the exponent part, I'm kind of sure of that :D

Comment: @pedja Have you tried dumping the values of exponent and mod prior to the "BigInteger result = n.modPow(exponent,mod);  " call in both cases, are they the same?

Comment: @pedja Could you please try adding println's between each operation in the second part to work out which one is actually failing?

Comment: @pedja How long does the first code section take to complete :)

Comment: @David,I have no idea..I guess few years :-)...What do you think ?

Comment: @pedja so when you say "the first code works fine", you mean it executes up to the modPow operation, but you haven't seen it complete?

Comment: @David,I am running the first code for the last two days...I still didn't get any error message..for the second code I am getting error message after two seconds..

Comment: Btw, what's the output of the first method? I'm just curious to see the calculated number ;)

Comment: @Thomas,Be sure that it isn't 1 :-)

Comment: @pedja I think with the first code you're probably stuck on the first pow calculation and have never actually hit the modPow, so saying "it works" is actually probably misleading.

Comment: @David,that might be true but on the other hand I know that there are memory-efficient algorithms for modular exponentiation so maybe it isn't problem .

Comment: @David,[memory-efficient methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method)

Comment: @pedja: I'm pretty sure that `java.math.BigInteger` has the most optimal algorithm for these things...

Comment: @LukasEder,I would like to know your opinion...How long the first code takes to complete ?

Comment: @Lukas Eder It does, it's based on the main C++ implementation and is heavily optimised. If this is important to work out, you're better off getting a really big Amazon instance and running it there

Comment: @pedja: I gave up after 20mins. Looking at `BigInteger.pow()`'s implementation, this algorithm is something like `O(log(n) * n^2)` with n being the exponent: `log(n)` is the "right shift loop" of the exponent until it reaches 0, and then there are roughly two nested loops over the length of the `BigInteger`'s internal `int[]`. The best way to find out how long this might take, is with heuristics and measurement. Measure `2^1`, `2^2`, `2^3`, etc and create a slope in MS Excel or some other tool. You can then extrapolate the time for your calculation to finish. Correct me if I missed something

Comment: @LukasEder,It seems that it is only way to find out...thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to calculate a number like `2 ^ (15 * 2 ^ 332192809)`. I don't know if you could even fit such a number in the universe!! Or maybe, the answer is simply... `42` ? ;-)

<s>On a more serious note, you'll really have trouble, calculating this number. Encoded in bits, `15 * 2 ^ 332192810` would require almost a gigabyte by itself. Then raising `2` to that power again, I don't want to know...</s>

On a more serious note, when you dig into the implementation of `java.math.BigInteger`, I think that you just run into such an error *faster* with the left shift, as that is implemented much more efficiently, than the power method. Having said this, have you tried to force garbage collection in your code, using `System.gc()`?

**UPDATE**:  My original reasoning might've been wrong. `2 ^ 332192809` can be calculated with 1GB. And the overall result might be "modded" efficiently by `java.math.BigInteger`, although I believe that this calculation might take a while...

Comment: no,I am not trying to calculate that number...Could you tell me why the first code works fine ?

Comment: @pedja Here's additional explanation: that number `2 ^ (15 * 2 ^ 332192809)` can be reordered to `(2^4) ^ ((15 * 2 ^ 332192809)/4)` => `16 ^ (15*2^(332192809-2))` => `16 ^(15 * 2^332192807)` => 16 ^ (15 * (2^4) ^ (332192807/4))` ~~> `16 ^ (15 * 16 ^ 83048201)`. Now for comparison read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex . Googolplex is a number 10 ^ (10 ^ 100). **Carl Sagan estimated that writing a googolplex in numerals (i.e.,"10,000,000,000...") would be physically impossible,since doing so would require more space than the known universe provides.** And your number is MUCH bigger.

Comment: @pedja: On what statement are you getting the error? On the left shift?

Comment: @Max: I think the point here is the `mod` at the end. So the result is not so big at all. I don't know if there's any math trick that can simplify the calculation, though

Comment: @Lukas Eder The poster is calculating exactly that in the first code section and it works, why is everyone in this thread ignoring that fact?

Comment: @LukasEder,"at java.math.BigInteger.modPow..."

Comment: @David I'm ignoring that "fact" because it doesn't work. I've just tested it.

Comment: @David,I don't know how modPow is implemented in Java but there are mathematical tricks to calculate modular exponentiation  without calculating 2^(15*2^332192809)...

Comment: @pedja: What happens if you enforce garbage collection before that call using `System.gc()`?

Comment: @LukasEder that won't help. When java notices it's low on memory - it forces GC automatically.

Comment: @Max: That's not entirely true. You can run into trouble in CPU-intensive situations when the GC context switch comes too late...

Comment: `have you tried to force garbage collection in your code` - note that you can't _force_ garabage collection. `System.gc()` is more of a hint: "Dear JVM, I'd like you to collect some garbage, if you want to.". The JVM will decide when and what to collect.

Comment: @Thomas: You're right. But in this case, it might create the necessary opportunity for the context switch that might not be possible due to CPU-intensive calculations. In other words, that's one way to make the main thread stop running havoc for a short instance

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess, but `BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(332192810);` will internally create an `int` array of length `x + 10381025`. Since an int is 4 bytes big you'll get about 40 mega bytes of data just for that one call. I assume the other calls copy that data around and thus you get that high a memory consumption.

Comment: My next question was going to be which line doest the exception occur on?

Comment: @Thomas: `BigInteger.pow()` creates a lot more `int[]` to come up with the same resulting `int[]`... It's just a lot slower

Comment: But Thomas' point is the temporary array created in this operation is most likely to be the source of the out of memory.